# Is there a way to `pipe through a list'?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, magrittr

One really cool feature from the `ggplot2` package that I never really exploited enough was adding lists of layers to a plot.  The fun thing about this was that I could pass a list of layers as an argument to a function and have them added to the plot.  I could then get the desired appearance of the plot without necessarily returning the plot from the function (whether or not this is a good idea is another matter, but it was possible).

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- ggplot(mtcars,
            aes(x = qsec,
                y = mpg)) 

layers <- list(geom_point(),
               geom_line(),
               xlab("Quarter Mile Time"),
               ylab("Fuel Efficiency"))

x + layers
```

Is there a way to do this with pipes?  Something akin to:

```
#* Obviously isn't going to work
library(dplyr)
action <- list(group_by(am, gear),
               summarise(mean = mean(mpg),
                         sd = sd(mpg)))

mtcars %>% action
```

Comment: That will do it!  Very neat.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To construct a sequence of magrittr steps, start with `.`

```
action = . %>% group_by(am, gear) %>% summarise(mean = mean(mpg), sd = sd(mpg))
```

Then it can be used as imagined in the OP:

```
mtcars %>% action
```

Like a `list`, we can subset to see each step:

```
action[[1]]
# function (.) 
# group_by(., am, gear)
```

To review all steps, use `functions(action)` or just type the name:

```
action
# Functional sequence with the following components:
# 
#  1. group_by(., am, gear)
#  2. summarise(., mean = mean(mpg), sd = sd(mpg))
# 
# Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```