# How to compose a list of functions

Tags: r

For example, I have a vector of functions: `fun_vec <- c(step1,step2,step3)`.
Now I want to compose them like this: `step1(step2(step3(x)))`. How do I do this using `fun_vec`? (Suppose that `fun_vec` isn't fixed and can have more or less functions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`purrr::compose`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/compose.html). If your functions are stored inside a list, use `purrr::invoke` to pass that list to `compose`:

```
fun_vec <- c( exp, log10, sqrt )
f <- purrr::invoke( purrr::compose, fun_vec )
f(4)                      # 1.35125
exp( log10( sqrt(4) ) )   # 1.35125
```

Comment: I guess they'll make `compose(!!!fun_vec)` work at some point, but not yet

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper [Funny you should mention that](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/564) :)

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Frank's use of `freduce`, you can use `Reduce`:

```
step1 <- function(a) a^2
step2 <- function(a) sum(a)
step3 <- function(a) sqrt(a)
steps <- list(step1, step2, step3)
Reduce(function(a,f) f(a), steps, 1:3)
# [1] 3.741657
step3(step2(step1(1:3)))
# [1] 3.741657
```

You can see it "in action" with:

```
Reduce(function(a,f) f(a), steps, 1:3, accumulate=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 4 9
# [[3]]
# [1] 14
# [[4]]
# [1] 3.741657
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use freduce from the magrittr package:

```
fun_vec = c(function(x) x^2, function(x) sum(x), function(x) sqrt(x))

library(magrittr)    
freduce(1:10, fun_vec)
```

Alternately, define a function sequence with pipes like...

```
library(magrittr)    
f = . %>% raise_to_power(2) %>% sum %>% sqrt

f(1:10)
```

A similar example: [Is there a way to `pipe through a list'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574610/is-there-a-way-to-pipe-through-a-list)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base R recursive approach:

```
compose <- function(funs) {
  n <- length(funs)
  fcomp <- function(x) funs[[n - 1]](funs[[n]](x))
  ifelse(n > 2, compose(c(funs[1:(n - 2)], fcomp)), fcomp)
}

x <- c(sqrt, log, exp)
compose(x)(2)
# [1] 1.414214
sqrt(log(exp(2)))
# [1] 1.414214
```

If the number of functions in `funs` is greater than two, we shorten the list by one by replacing the last two functions by their composition. Otherwise, we return the composition of the last remaining two. It's assumed that initially there are at least two functions in `funs`.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `ifelse` vice just `if` here?

Comment: Only compactness.

Comment: Then using `if` with the backticks, as a regular function, will be more compact and more correct